# Datatype of Text in export to Excel from DocXfactory

Tags: excel, types, xlsx

I am using DocXfactory to write data to XLSX which is coming from a table where the field is defined as text (CHARACTER). The cell type in Excel also turns into TEXT which implies that you cannot type a formula in such a cell. Is there a way to tell DocXfactory to use the "General" datatype in XLSX instead of "Text"? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can add formulas manually in the Excel template but you can also add formulas programmatically using the ttMeta temp-table.

You can enter Excel formulas using Excel syntax and functions but you can also use 4gl/abl buffer-field or calculated field names in formulas.

You can also reference a column previous row by adding :PrevRow option to the field name. The following options are also supported - :NextRow,:PrevCol,:NextCol.

Please have a look at the create_template_ttmeta.p procedure in the \progress\samples\src\excel directory.

Comment: Yes, I found the option to use the ttMeta table. But is is unclear to me how I can use this to change the format to "General" on all exported cells. Actually, I am looking for a way to have "General" as the default format for all exported cells without having to use any additional calls. The create_template_ttmeta.p requires a pipe separated list of field names to be passed in. As the field used for this is a CHARACTER variable, this means that one can easily exceed the 32K limit for CHAR variables for spreadsheets with many columns. So this is not a feasible option.

Comment: Looking deeper into this, I found that changing the type to "General" does not resolve the issue. Apparently DocXfactory applies a format to the cells (resulting among other things in the purple coloring). If I remove the formatting, then Excel suddenly start to show info on numeric cells that they are formatted as text. So to rephrase my issue: Is there a way to have DocXfactory generate the output without applying the purple formatting to the output?